# RGBA Hex from RGB Hex

Tags: c, colors, hex, rgb, rgba

I want to make from color like `0xFF0000` (RGB), an RGBA color with FF alpha, like `0xFF0000FF`. It will be something with bits, I think.

Thanks in advance,
Kacper

Comment: @Christoffer, look at his tags. I'm assuming he wants it in C. I do recommend adding a bit more description though regardless, I almost downvoted the question until I saw the C tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint32_t rgb=0xFF0000;
uint32_t rgba = (rgb << 8) | 0xFF;
```

**Explanation:** `(rgb << 8)` shifts the rgb value by 8 bits to the left. it means it moves exactly one byte left so for example `0x12345678` will change to `0x34567800`. The top two digits won't fit in 32 bits after shifting, so they are removed. Every thing else shifts left and then new zeroes are added in the low position.

The next operator is a bitwise `or`. it's an or applied on every bit so `0x34567800 | 0xFF` will result in `0x345678FF`

(thanks to @Gajet for explanation)

Comment: @Kacper the uint32_t type is in <stdint.h> so don't forget to include it. +1

Comment: explanation: `(rgb << 8)` shifts the rgb value by 8 bits. it means it moves exactly one byte left so for example `0x12345678` will change to `0x34567800`. first two large digits are removed, every one shifts and then new zeroes are added in the low position. the next operator is `bitwise or`. it's an `or` applied on every bit so `0x34567800 | 0xff` will result in `0x345678ff`

Comment: @hexa good point. you could optionally use `uint_least32_t` or if you know that you're working on a platform with 32bit ints use `unsigned int`

Comment: @Gajet I put your explanation in my answer